# How to export function names and variable names using GCC or clang?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I am making a commercial software and I don't want for it to be easily crackable. It is targeted for Linux and I am compiling it using GCC (8.2.1). The problem is that when I compile it, technically anyone can use disassembler like IDA or Binary Ninja to see all functions names. Here is example (you can see function names on left panel):

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to protect my program from this kind if reverse engineering? Is there any way of exporting all if these function names and variables from code automatically (with GCC or clang?), so I can make a simple script to change them to completely random before compilation?

Comment: You're looking for the keyword "strip".

Comment: Obfuscate your code, or strip the symbols.

Comment: Bit of an XY question, this. No matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to hide/mask the names of symbols in your binary. You've decided that, to do this, you need to get a list of them so that you can create a script to modify them. Well, you could get that list with `nm` but you don't need any of that (rewriting names inside a compiled binary? oof… recipe for disaster).

Instead, just do what everybody does in a release build and [`strip`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-strip/) the symbols! You'll see a much smaller binary, too. Of course this doesn't prevent reverse engineering (nothing does), though it arguably makes said task more difficult.

Honestly you should be stripping your release binaries anyway, and not to prevent cracking. Common wisdom is not to try too hard to prevent cracking, because you'll inevitably fail, and at the cost of wasted dev time in the attempt (and possibly a more complex codebase that's harder to maintain / a more complex executable that is less fast and/or useful for the honest customer).

Comment: Good answer, but please take the time to provide a simple example of using `strip`, so that your answer can be more useful on its own.

Comment: @yzt I'm not going to do that. I linked to the reference, and learning to read the reference is a critical part of developing ones programmer talents. It's not like using `strip` is complex.. you literally just invoke it.

Comment: In addition to this answer which I think answers pretty much everything if you are into embedded you can also check "sstrip" https://github.com/BR903/ELFkickers/tree/master/sstrip . It is simple tool that have  such properties people complain about it http://lists.en.qi-hardware.com/pipermail/discussion/2011-January/006709.html

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, it seems that the SO community somewhat disagrees with you on the subject of what constitutes a "good" answer (e.g. [How To Write a Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). [Meta, on answers that just link elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), and [on Writing Good Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question). But it's your call. I certainly don't care about this one Q and A.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Yes. I was trying to be polite and encouraging. *woosh*